# Agrupar resultados en MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Tengo una colección en mongoDB como la descrita abajo,
En esta coleccion guardo informacion de las marcaciones de las horas del personal.

aplico el siguiente filtro en mongoDB

```
db.getCollection('Marcaciones').find({"uuid": "12345",
                                    "fecha_registro" : {"$gte": ISODate("2019-06-20 00:00:00.000Z")},
                                    "fecha_registro" : {"$lte": ISODate("2019-06-25 23:59:59.999Z")}
                                     },
                                     {'fecha_registro':1,'_id':0}
                              ).sort({'fecha_registro':-1})
```

pero no conozco como agrupar las fechas y/o algo similar al distinct en MongoDB

de esta coleccion como puedo obtener el siguiente resultado

```
{"fecha_registro": "2019-06-20"},
{"fecha_registro": "2019-06-21"},
{"fecha_registro": "2019-06-22"},
{"fecha_registro": "2019-06-23"},
{"fecha_registro": "2019-06-24"},
{"fecha_registro": "2019-06-25"}
```

Gracias de antemano por toda la ayuda brindada.

Colección

```
db.Marcaciones.insert({ "uuid": "12345", "tipo": "1", "fecha_registro": ISODate("2019-06-19 09:11:45.285Z") })
db.Marcaciones.insert({ "uuid": "12345", "tipo": "2", "fecha_registro": ISODate("2019-06-19 12:22:22.665Z") })
db.Marcaciones.insert({ "uuid": "12345", "tipo": "3", "fecha_registro": ISODate("2019-06-19 12:54:55.788Z") })
db.Marcaciones.insert({ "uuid": "12345", "tipo": "4", "fecha_registro": ISODate("2019-06-19 18:07:10.138Z") })

db.Marcaciones.insert({ "uuid": "12345", "tipo": "1", "fecha_registro": ISODate("2019-06-20 08:47:12.982Z") })
db.Marcaciones.insert({ "uuid": "12345", "tipo": "2", "fecha_registro": ISODate("2019-06-20 12:23:24.866Z") })
db.Marcaciones.insert({ "uuid": "12345", "tipo": "3", "fecha_registro": ISODate("2019-06-20 13:00:28.387Z") })
db.Marcaciones.insert({ "uuid": "12345", "tipo": "4", "fecha_registro": ISODate("2019-06-20 17:59:57.922Z") })

db.Marcaciones.insert({ "uuid": "12345", "tipo": "1", "fecha_registro": ISODate("2019-06-21 08:51:17.527Z") })
db.Marcaciones.insert({ "uuid": "12345", "tipo": "2", "fecha_registro": ISODate("2019-06-21 12:20:23.028Z") })
db.Marcaciones.insert({ "uuid": "12345", "tipo": "3", "fecha_registro": ISODate("2019-06-21 12:46:06.670Z") })

db.Marcaciones.insert({ "uuid": "12345", "tipo": "1", "fecha_registro": ISODate("2019-06-22 09:06:18.442Z") })
db.Marcaciones.insert({ "uuid": "12345", "tipo": "2", "fecha_registro": ISODate("2019-06-22 13:24:17.891Z") })
db.Marcaciones.insert({ "uuid": "12345", "tipo": "3", "fecha_registro": ISODate("2019-06-22 13:31:00.606Z") })
db.Marcaciones.insert({ "uuid": "12345", "tipo": "4", "fecha_registro": ISODate("2019-06-22 13:31:05.537Z") })

db.Marcaciones.insert({ "uuid": "12345", "tipo": "1", "fecha_registro": ISODate("2019-06-24 08:51:21.862Z") })
db.Marcaciones.insert({ "uuid": "12345", "tipo": "2", "fecha_registro": ISODate("2019-06-24 12:28:49.500Z") })
db.Marcaciones.insert({ "uuid": "12345", "tipo": "3", "fecha_registro": ISODate("2019-06-24 13:08:36.422Z") })
db.Marcaciones.insert({ "uuid": "12345", "tipo": "4", "fecha_registro": ISODate("2019-06-24 18:00:41.499Z") })

db.Marcaciones.insert({ "uuid": "12345", "tipo": "1", "fecha_registro": ISODate("2019-06-25 08:49:03.776Z") })
db.Marcaciones.insert({ "uuid": "12345", "tipo": "2", "fecha_registro": ISODate("2019-06-25 13:27:05.152Z") })
db.Marcaciones.insert({ "uuid": "12345", "tipo": "3", "fecha_registro": ISODate("2019-06-25 13:44:02.609Z") })

db.Marcaciones.insert({ "uuid": "12345", "tipo": "1", "fecha_registro": ISODate("2019-06-26 08:49:06.356Z") })
db.Marcaciones.insert({ "uuid": "12345", "tipo": "2", "fecha_registro": ISODate("2019-06-26 12:30:52.041Z") })
db.Marcaciones.insert({ "uuid": "12345", "tipo": "3", "fecha_registro": ISODate("2019-06-26 13:18:37.833Z") })
db.Marcaciones.insert({ "uuid": "12345", "tipo": "4", "fecha_registro": ISODate("2019-06-26 18:02:35.837Z") })

db.Marcaciones.insert({ "uuid": "12345", "tipo": "1", "fecha_registro": ISODate("2019-06-27 08:43:45.077Z") })
db.Marcaciones.insert({ "uuid": "12345", "tipo": "2", "fecha_registro": ISODate("2019-06-27 12:33:16.952Z") })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para realizar la tarea podrías usar un método de [agregación](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/index.html). Así, vas construyendo por [etapas](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/index.html) el documento que esperas obtener al final.

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea agrupar por un campo específico diferentes documentos de MongoDB. El campo sobre el cual se desea realizar la agrupación es de tipo [`Date`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/shell-types/#date). El documento tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
{ 
  "_id": <ObjectId>,
  "uuid": <String>, 
  "tipo": <String>,
  "fecha_registro": <Date>
}
```

Se desea que el documento devuelto tenga la siguiente estructura:

```
{"fecha_registro": "2019-06-20"},
{"fecha_registro": "2019-06-21"},
{"fecha_registro": "2019-06-22"},
{"fecha_registro": "2019-06-23"},
{"fecha_registro": "2019-06-24"},
{"fecha_registro": "2019-06-25"}
```

Las *fechas* devueltas corresponden a un rango específico. Además, se desea ordenar de forma ascendente (más antiguo primero).

**SOLUCIÓN**

Para lograr el resultado deseado debemos tomar en cuenta lo siguiente:

> El campo `fecha_registro` contiene un valor de tipo `Date`, por lo tanto realizar el agrupamiento directamente sobre dicho campo no producirá el resultado esperado, ya que si el valor difiere en 1 milisegundo entre fechas, las mismas se consideran diferentes.

Una opción para realizar la agrupación es la siguiente: dado que deseas hacerla mostrando sólo la parte correspondiente a `YYYY-MM-DD` del campo `fecha_registro` debemos convertir dicho campo en un tipo `String` y agrupar luego sobre dicho campo.

El código de agregación puede quedar de la siguiente manera:

```
db.getCollection('Marcaciones').aggregate([
  {$match:
    {
      $and: [
        {'uuid': '12345'},
        {'fecha_registro':
          {
            $gte: ISODate('2019-06-20 00:00:00.000Z'),
            $lte: ISODate('2019-06-25 23:59:59.999Z')
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      fecha_registro: {
        $dateToString: {
          date: '$fecha_registro',
          format: '%Y-%m-%d'
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: { _id: '$fecha_registro'}
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      fecha_registro: '$_id'
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      fecha_registro: -1
    }
  },
]);
```

**Explicación**

La agregación antes planteada realiza 5 etapas, las cuales explico a continuación:

**Etapa [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/index.html):**

En esta etapa se realiza una búsqueda en la colección para encontrar los documentos que cumplan con 2 condiciones:

- `{"uuid": "12345"}`: Indica que filtre los documentos que tengan dicho valor en el campo `uuid`.
- `{"fecha_registro": {$gte: ISODate('2019-06-20 00:00:00.000Z'), $lte: ISODate('2019-06-25 23:59:59.999Z')}`: Indica que filtre los documentos cuyas fechas de registro se encuentren entre los valores pasados a [`gte`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/gte/index.html) y [`lte`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lte/index.html).

Dado que deseamos que ambas condiciones se cumplan, entonces usamos el operador [`$and`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/and/index.html).

**Etapa [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/index.html):**

En esta etapa le indicaremos a MongoDB que realice una conversión del campo `fecha_registro` de tipo `Date` a un tipo `String`. Para lograrlo usaremos el operador [`$dateToString`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/index.html).

El resultado de la conversión será almacenado en un campo llamado `fecha_registro`, además, como no le indicamos a Mongo ningún otro campo, el documento resultante sólo contendrá el campo `_id` y el campo `fecha_registro` recién creado.

Una de las cosas que haremos al convertir el campo es darle el formato deseado, para ello usaremos el siguiente [especificador de formato](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/index.html#format-specifiers): `'%Y-%m-%d'`.

**Etapa [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html):**

En esta etapa, agruparemos los documentos usando como clave el valor del campo `fecha_registro`, el cuál ahora es un tipo `String`.

**Segunda etapa `$project`:**

Ahora realizamos una etapa para cambiar el nombre del campo `_id` (generado durante la etapa de agrupación anterior) por `fecha_registro`. Este paso es necesario para poder mostrar los valores de acuerdo al campo especificado en la salida.

**Etapa [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/index.html):**

Esta es la última etapa de nuestra agregación, la misma se encarga de ordenar los valores devueltos de forma ascendente:

```
{
    $sort: {
      fecha_registro: 1 //ascendente (más antiguo primero)
    }
}
```

Nótese que si deseamos ordenar de forma descendente (más reciente primero), debemos usar el valor `-1` (negativo de uno):

```
{
    $sort: {
      fecha_registro: -1 // descendente (más reciente primero)
    }
}
```

Des esta forma se obtiene el resultado esperado.

**Consideración final**

Recuerda que el método `aggregate` de MongoDB devuelve el resultado en un tipo `Array`, por lo tanto, cada documento devuelto por dicho método corresponderá a un elemento del array.

Espero que esta sea la respuesta que esperabas y te ayude a resolver el problema.

> **Nota:** Esta solución fue probada usando MongoDB 4.0.

Comment: Muchas gracias estimado @MauricioContreras. La respuesta es muy útil.